# How to get the time difference between 2 timestamps

Tags: pyspark

I have tried below code and it gives me -55 as difference between above 2 time_stamps. It should give me 5 minutes. Is there any direct function to get correct time difference in `pyspark`?

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# ts1 := 2019-11-07T22:00:00.000+0000 
# ts2 := 2019-11-07T21:55:00.000+0000

df.withColumn("time_diff", F.minute("time_stamp") - F.minute("time_stamp2"))
```

Doesn't give me correct answer. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to get the time difference in seconds:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
diff_secs_col = col("time_stamp").cast("long") - col("time_stamp2").cast("long")
```

Then do the math to get in minutes.

Comment: I am getting null using above function:
df.withColumn("time_diff",col("time_stamp2").cast("long") - col("time_stamp").cast("long")).show()
+----------+-------------+---------+--------------------+---------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+
|Percentage|    Unixtime2|dayofweek|           host_name|hourofday|            kpi_name|kpi_subtype|          time_stamp|         time_stamp2|time_diff|
|      60.0|1573163700000|        5|.|       21|XXX...| |2019-11-07T21:55:...|2019-11-07T22:00:...|     null|

Comment: Don't use that. Just use the one I added

Comment: this doesnt show me any value:
>>> diff_secs_col = col("time_stamp").cast("long") - col("time_stamp2").cast("long")
>>>
>>> diff_secs_col
Column<b'(CAST(time_stamp AS BIGINT) - CAST(time_stamp2 AS BIGINT))'>

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as Types
df = df.withColumn('t1_unix', F.unix_timestamp(df.t1, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"))
df = df.withColumn('t2_unix', F.unix_timestamp(df.t2, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"))
df = df.withColumn('diff', ((df.t1_unix-df.t2_unix)/60).cast(Types.IntegerType()))
```